# Is E.T's Visit To Earth Considered Canon?

Tags: star-wars

In Episode I, E.T's race the Asogians are seen in the Galactic Senate, we know that they were part of the Star Wars universe but are they still considered canon? Was E.T's visit to Earth considered canon as well?

Comment: If there can be parallel versions of humans in the Star Wars galaxy that share no common ancestry with humans on Earth, it's possible the beings in the Galactic Senate are parallel versions of E.T.'s race that evolved on a different world than E.T.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - Given that Star Wars happens "A long time ago", it's possible the spread of intergalactic species from that galaxy "far far away" have colonised closer. Hell, E.T.'s initial reasons for being in the neighbourhood could've been a scouting trip looking for viable planets in which to colonise and/or extract raw materials.